# How to encode HTML WYSIWYG editor CKEditor?

Tags: php, performance, encoding, ckeditor, encode

I use the WYSIWYG editor CKEditor on my site. I have a problem if I take a javascript script in the editor and I send these changes. It shows me a popup instead of show me the HTML string. I try to encode the text I typed but it encodes all the code created by the editor (bold, underline).

I also tried to use the configuration using the WYSIWYG editor:

> config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;

By typing `<script> alert ('test') </ script>` in the editor, it displays correctly on the display. But if I want to re-edit my code, he wrote me this in the editor:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;test&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this code to ckeditor/config.js:

```
config.basicEntities = false;
config.entities = false;
```

Also make sure ACF is setup to not strip your code. More this here:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter

Answer (score 0):

try php htmlspecialchars_decode($text) function http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php on your edit page where you pass old text

This should help

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried but it does not work

Comment: How do you pass it to db ?